# Set Permission CKAN DATASTORE?

Tags: python, ckan

I successfully installed CKAN2.8 from source to Ubuntu 18.04 Then continued to "Setting up the DataStore". following the docs from the development version : https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html,  in something that I can not understand.

command:

`paster datastore set-permissions postgres -c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini`

error:

```
  File "/usr/bin/paster", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PasteScript==2.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
  File "/home/ads/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 101, in run
    command = commands[command_name].load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2305, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2311, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/home/ads/src/ckan/ckanext/datastore/commands.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ckanext.datastore.view import DUMP_FORMATS, dump_to
  File "/home/ads/src/ckan/ckanext/datastore/view.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ckanext.datastore.logic.schema import (
  File "/home/ads/src/ckan/ckanext/datastore/logic/schema.py", line 25, in <module>
    configured_default = get_validator('configured_default')
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/logic/__init__.py", line 687, in get_validator
    raise UnknownValidator('Validator `%s` does not exist' % validator)
ckan.logic.UnknownValidator: Validator `configured_default` does not exist
```

I like some help to know what I should do with this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use following command:

```
paster --plugin=ckan datastore set-permissions -c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini | sudo -u postgres psql --set ON_ERROR_STOP=1
```